Managing Kafka Message Retrieval and Data Delay
I've recently started learning about Apache Kafka. In my scenario, I have over 1000 customers, and they're all sending their location data to the "location" topic in Kafka, which has 10 partitions and a replication factor of 3. Each message sent to the topic includes a "truck_id" key.

If a particular truck sends its location message, but it's placed a million messages behind in the topic's offset, does that mean I won't be able to retrieve that message immediately? Is there a way to fetch messages based on the truck ID instead?

Let's say I have 50 partitions for the "location" topic, distributing the location data of 1000 customers across these partitions. This means each partition is handling location data for 20 customers. If the data for a specific customer is located in a partition and is significantly behind the offset of that partition, causing data delay, how should I address this issue?


Certainly, here's the updated response:
For message retrieval based on truck ID, I attempted to use Kafka consumer APIs for filtering. However, I found this approach inefficient for large message backlogs.
Regarding data delay, I considered increasing partition count but was unsure if it would effectively address the issue. Specifically, I'm implementing this in Java, and the delay is primarily on the consumer end. After polling a batch of offsets, the consumer needs to perform some processing before it can poll again for the next batch.
Expectation: Efficient message retrieval based on truck ID and minimal data delay for real-time processing.
Thank You.

More partitions might help, but it's not guaranteed data will be equally distributed when using message keys. Regarding processing speed, how many consumers do you have? Try parallelism? https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer

2 consumer. Not sure though. What is the reasonable count regarding my scenario?

You can run as many consumers as partitions for optimal consumption rates

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
